# "expected a qualified name after 'typename'" when I try to use iterator inside of a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I want to make a function that takes a container T (can be vector, map, list...) as template and a T and a Int as arguments, in this function, we're assuming that T is a container of int, and I want to return the first occurence of the int in the container. Here's the function:

```
template <class T> int & easyfind(T container, int n)
{
    typename T<int>::iterator it;

    for (it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); it++)
        if (*it == n)
            return (*it);
    throw (NotFoundException());
}
```

But the compiler says "expected a qualified name after 'typename'", and when I replace the `typename` by `class` the compiler says "explicit specialization of non-template class 'T'", how can I get this to work?

Comment: You're assuming that `T` is a container of `int`, so you don't have to specify that. `T<int>::iterator` --> `T::iterator`.

Comment: Not the answer, but `()` after `throw` are superfluous.

Comment: thanks, i don't know why i thought it didn't work without the <int> but it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is a type, not a template.  You need

```
typename T::iterator it;
```

to access its `iterator` type member.

The reason you see code like

```
std::vector<int>::iterator
```

is because `std::vector` is the name of a template, and you need to specify the template parameter.  In your case `T` is already an instantiation of a template, so there is no need to specify the parameter.

Comment: thanks, it works, I thought I tested this but I didn't :)

Comment: Now it says I can't compare *it with n? why ? isnt operator * returning a reference ?

Comment: @Fayeure It depends on the container.  If you are using a vector, then it should work.  If you are using a `map` then `*it` is a `std::pair<const key, value>`.